# Inserting script for bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

I have a bootstrap 4 popover with list inside which comes from a viewcomponent element (asp net core 3.1 project).
This popover is inside layout navigation bar (not sure if that's relevant) and after hovering over it the list should appear.
Now every list element appears correctly but after I click any of the list elements I want to send ajax post request but I cannot make my javascript work. I am not sure what is the problem. Is it because my script is only loaded when I hover on popover? Am I using events incorrectly? I tried a lot of variations to test if JS is working and seems like everything failed.
ViewComponent:

```
@model mymodel;

    <div class='list-group'>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Item)
        {

            <a href='@item.Url' class='btn list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1'>You have been invited to join event: <b>@item.Name</b></a>

        }

        @foreach (var item in Model.AnotherItem)
        {

            <a id='lmao' href='#' onclick='doSomething(@item.Id);' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action mb-1'>You have been invited to join team: <b>@item.Name</b></a>
        }
    </div>

<script>
    $('#lmao').click(function () { MyFunction(); return false; });

    function MyFunction() {
        alert('hello');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this);
    }
</script>
```

_Layout Page with popover:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Settings
                        </a>
                        ...
                            <a tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item pop" data-container="body" data-html="true" title="Your invitations" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="@await Component.InvokeAsync("InvitationList")" style="cursor: pointer;">Invitations (number coming from another viewcomponent)</a>
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </li>
                   ...
```

Popover JS in Layout:

```
<script>
        $('.pop').popover({
            trigger: 'manual',
            html: true
        })
            .on('mouseenter', function () {
                var _this = this;
                $(this).popover('show');
                $('.popover').on('mouseleave', function () {
                    $(_this).popover('hide');
                });
            }).on('mouseleave', function () {
                var _this = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!$('.popover:hover').length) {
                        $(_this).popover('hide');
                    }
                }, 300);
            });

    </script>
```

My popover works correctly, I see the items loaded from viewcomponent, I can press on each of them and go to preset href.
What doesn't work is javascript coming from viewcomponent or atleast I am failing to test it. My end goal is to make a post call if any of the items in the popover are clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your codes and found if you directly call viewcomponent in data-content, the jacascripts in ViewComponent will be recongnized as html, so it will never be called. Instead, you can define an area for viewcomponent separately

```
<a id="invitations" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item pop" data-container="body" data-html="true" title="Your invitations" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" style="cursor: pointer;" data-content="">invitations</a>

<div id="vc" style="display:none">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("InvitationList")
</div>
```

Use js to append it to data-content

```
$("#invitations").attr("data-content", $("#vc").html())
```

Since it is a new element from other page, the handler won't be bound on that new element, your click function should be like this:

```
<script>
    $('body').on('click', '#lmao', function () { MyFunction(); return false; });

    function MyFunction() {
        alert('hello');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this);
    }

</script>
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: big thanks, works as intended after I attached your changes!